# Desanidar lista con diccionarios anidados mediante lista de comprensión

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

Hola tengo una lista con diccionarios anidados y quisiera saber como desanidar mediante lista de comprensión, logre hacerlo mediante bucle for pero no logro ver como hacerlo  por comprensión con  if/else, lo que necesito es desanidar solo el de clave 'moClass' que es el anidado, ejemplo:

```
mo = [{'moId': 'PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-921838/LNBTS-921838/ANRPRL-2', 'moClass': {'id': 
     'NOKLTE:ANRPRL', 'version': 'xL21B_2105_002'}}, {'moId': 'PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-921838/LNBTS- 
      921838/ANRPRL-3', 'moClass': {'id': 'NOKLTE:ANRPRL', 'version': 'xL21B_2105_002'}}]


ver = []
for sub in mo:
   res = {}

   for key, val in sub.items():
      if key == 'moClass':
        for k, v in val.items():
            res[k] = v
      else:
        res[key] = val
   ver.append(res) 


ver = [{'moId': 'PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-921838/LNBTS-921838/ANRPRL-2', 'id': 'NOKLTE:ANRPRL', 
      'version': 'xL21B_2105_002'}, {'moId': 'PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-921838/LNBTS- 921838/ANRPRL-3', 
      'id': 'NOKLTE:ANRPRL', 'version': 'xL21B_2105_002'}]
```

intente hacer algo pero no logro entender como hacerlo funcionar ok, solo me genera las de 'moClass'

```
v = [{k:v} for sub in mo for key,val in sub.items() if key == 'moClass' for k,v in val.items() ]
```

desde ya gracias por su tiempo, saludos

Comment: No puedes, una llist comprehension hace cosas simples y concretas, no puedes poner condiciones muy complejas, aunque creo que puedes lograrlo si ejecutas una función

Comment: Gracias @Christian por la pronta respuesta,  o sea, mediante comprensión no puedo llegar al resultado que busco? si es así ya no pierdo mas tiempo y creo una función para esto!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Ese arreglo tiene siempre las mismas claves? Si es así, una forma fácil, aunque poco elegante, de hacerlo por comprensión puede ser:

```
[{'moId':x['moId'], 'id':x['moClass']['id'], 'version':x['moClass']['version']} for x in mo]
```

Comment: excelente @aeportugal era lo que buscaba, como resolver este tipo de problemas con  lista comprensión... gracias